# TailwindCSS use @apply with placeholder color

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to use `@apply` together with placeholder color in TailwindCSS, but for some reason, it does not seem to work although I am able to use `@apply` together with other properties. I am also able to use the placeholder color options as a CSS class. It just doesn't work with `@apply`.

```css
@tailwind base;

input {
  @apply placeholder-gray-900;
}

@tailwind components;

@tailwind utilities;
```

By trying this I end up with this error:

```
`@apply` cannot be used with `.placeholder-gray-900` because `.placeholder-gray-900` either cannot be found, or its actual definition includes a pseudo-selector like :hover, :active, etc. If you're sure that `.placeholder-gray-900` exists, make sure that any `@import` statements are being properly processed *before* Tailwind CSS sees your CSS, as `@apply` can only be used for classes in the same CSS tree.
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is because the placeholder text is changed with a pseudo-selector, `::placeholder`. If you look at the [placeholder docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/placeholder-color/) it's shown in light gray after each class definition.

As you can't `@apply` classes with a pseudo-selector, you'll need to add the pseudo-selector to your code, something like this (note you'll need to use the text color utilities here):

```
input::placeholder {
  @apply text-gray-900;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For v2.1.4 ...

By default, the active variant is not enabled for any core plugins. Maybe its actual definition includes a pseudo-selector like :hover, :active, etc. You can control whether active variants are enabled for a plugin in the variants section of your tailwind.config.js file:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  variants: {
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: ['active'],
    }
  },
}
```

[Read here for Tailwind - Hover, Focus, & Other States](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#active)